# VB.Net XMLReader check if value is empty

Tags: xml, vb.net, datagridview

I want to create a program which reads xml file and puts obtained values into DataGridView.
This XML file is a table dump from MySQL database. In this table I have a 'set' column where I can choose some options. Here's an example with no selected options

```
<size></size>
```

and with selected option

```
<size>SMALL,MEDIUM,LARGE,XLARGE</size>
```

Here is my code which I use to read xml file:

```
    Dim ofile As New OpenFileDialog
    If ofile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim reader As XmlTextReader = New XmlTextReader(ofile.FileName)
        Using reader
            Dim toadd As String = Nothing
            Dim str() As String
            Do While (reader.Read())
                Select Case reader.NodeType
                    Case XmlNodeType.Element
                        If reader.Name.ToLower.Contains("oldIndex") Then
                            Exit Select
                        End If
                    Case XmlNodeType.Text
                        If Not reader.Value = vbNullString Or Not reader.Value = vbNullChar Then
                            toadd = toadd & reader.Value & vbTab
                        Else
                            toadd = toadd & "no data" & vbTab
                        End If
                    Case XmlNodeType.EndElement
                        If reader.Name.Contains("RECORD") Then
                            If toadd IsNot Nothing Then
                                str = toadd.Split(vbTab)
                                ShopTable.Rows.Add(str)
                                toadd = Nothing
                            End If
                        End If
                End Select
            Loop
        End Using
    End If
```

When there are some data between *size* tags, there is no problem with reading, but if there are no data, then it reads nothing and I don't receive 'no data' as a result. How do I fix this? Thanks in advance for help. Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I had to rewrite my algorithm. My xml file contained data in this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
 <RECORDS>
  <RECORD>
   <customerID>101</customerID>
   <name>Gall Anonim</name>
   <item>t-shirt</item>
   <size></size>
   ...
  </RECORD>
 </RECORDS>
```

I cound't get value of `size` field, it wasn't event empty. So I used algorithm below to get direct value of `size` element ;)

```
Dim ofile As New OpenFileDialog
If ofile.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    Dim sr As New System.IO.StreamReader(ofile.FileName)
    Dim document As XDocument = XDocument.Parse(sr.ReadToEnd.ToString)
    Dim records = From record In document.Descendants("RECORD") _
                  Select New With _
                     { _
                        .cID = record.Element("customerID").Value, _
                        .name = Chr(&H22) & record.Element("name").Value & Chr(&H22), _
                        .item = record.Element("item").Value, _
                        .size = record.Element("size").Value _
                     }
    MsgBox(records.cID) 'shows customer id
    do some work with those variables
    ...
End If
```

Problem solved.